# PHP Recordset and EOF

Tags: php, eof, recordset

I feel like I know this, but am getting frustrated that I can't remember exactly how to do this.

In PHP, I need to repeat items of a record set in a unordered list. I can repeat items fine, but I don't want anything to show if the record set is empty. Right now, if there is no record, the code is still displaying a blank list item, when I just want nothing to appear.

I have tried this:

```
<?php do { ?>
    <li><a href="#">Content Goes Here</a></li>
<?php } while (!feof($recordsetName) && $row_recordsetName = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordsetName)); ?>
```

And I have tried doing it this way by putting the repeating element withing an if/else statement like this:

```
<?php if (!feof($recordsetName)) {
    echo ""; }
else do { ?>
    <li><a href="#">Content Goes Here</a></li>
<?php } while ($row_recordsetName = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordsetName));
; } ?>
```

But that isn't working either. Any information would be helpful

Comment: I think there is a simpler way to accomplish this. Can you show what your db structure/queries look like and also what do you want your end result to look like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordsetName)) {
    if($row['fieldname'] != '') {
        echo '<li><a href="#">Content Goes Here</a></li>';
    }
}
```

or you could check if the query was successful...

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result) {
    echo '<li><a href="#">Content Goes Here</a></li>';
}
```

or if it returned any results...

```
$results = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordsetName);
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
       echo '<li><a href="#">Content Goes Here</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Also, you should really be using `mysqli` or `PDO`, as `mysql` is depreciated.

Edit: added loop in example 3.

Comment: That isn't working. Maybe I can try clarifying. If a recordset is empty, nothing should happen, otherwise, if there are items returned in the recordset, then it should loop through each and show each item from the recorodset in a list item. Maybe that will help clarify.

Comment: Example 1 won't display anything if the field is empty. Example 2 won't display anything if the query failed. Example 3 won't display anything if the recordset is empty - which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Tim. I was actually able to figure that part out just before I saw your answer, but seeing yours reconfirmed my thoughts, and I was able to get it working. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! glad to hear it's working. Please accept my answer so other people will not try and answer in the future, and it won't show up in the unanswered category. :)

Comment: Thanks - first time using this site, so hopefully I'll get the hang of it sooner or later.